# Can the mobilefirst server use port 9080 while the mobilefirst console use port 9090?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, mobilefirst-server

I have set my mobileFirst platform foundation v7 hybrid app to communicate with the worklight server using the port 9080 (defined it in worklight.properties and also built the app to communicate through it).

The problem I have is the following: 
I want to change the port of the url console from  `http://MyUrl.com:**9080**/worklightconsole/index.html` to `http://MyUrl.com:**9090**/worklightconsole/index.html`.

I am updating the server.xml file but if I change the ibm.worklight.admin.endpoint to

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="worklightconsole/ibm.worklight.admin.endpoint" value='"http://myUrl.com:9090/wladmin"'/>
```

and  httpEndpoint to

```
<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
              host="*"
              httpPort="9080"
              httpsPort="9443" >
```

the console opens but the app is no longer communicating with the server.
What steps must I do in order to achieve what I want?

Comment: unfortunately the liberty profile can not have two http endpoints simultaneously (9080 and 9090) .

Comment: unfortunately the liberty profile can not have two http endpoints simultaneously (9080 and 9090) . so if you change  httpPort="9090" you also need to edit the regular expr for wladmin (I would leave it "*://*:*/wladmin ). btw: no need for triple qoutes. single qoute will work.

Comment: So what I want to do cannot be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the port in the URL: http://myserver:port, the port is the port number of the *server*. So if you change 9080 to 9090 it is the server's port that you have change from 9080 to 9090, there is no 2 sets of ports to use. It's either 9080 or 9090.

As such, what @taitelman wrote in the comments section of the question is correct.

You may experiment further with this using Virtual Hosts in WebSphere Liberty if you'd like to (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/cwlp_virtual_hosts.html). However note that this is not a supported feature by MobileFirst.

Why is this a requirement?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Idan. This is a rquirement because we want the app to communicate with the adapters on 9080 but we don't want outside access to the console and appcenter urls through that port. That's why we need to change just the ports of the console and the appcenter

Comment: That's what firewall rules, reverse proxies, load balancers and secure topologies are for.